# Error in if...end-if stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, syntax-error

```
drop procedure if exists test;

delimiter $$
create procedure `test`() 
begin 
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE i1 VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE i2 DATE;
    DECLARE i3 VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE i4 INT; 
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test11;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN curs1; 
    FETCH curs1 INTO i1,i2,i3,i4;
    if i4=22 then
        insert into test1(abc) values(i1);
    end if ;
    CLOSE curs1; 
end ;

;;
delimiter ;
```

above throws an error : `SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14`

```
create table test11(abc varchar(20), cde varchar(20), eg varchar(20), asda varchar(20));
insert into test11 values("Hello",'1989-08-09','sdads','22');

create table test1(abc varchar(20), cde int(20), eg date, asda varchar(20));
```

I don't what i am doing wrong. Syntax seems to be fine.

```
drop procedure if exists sp;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp()
BEGIN
  DECLARE intoffer INT;
  SELECT max(asda) INTO intoffer FROM test11;
  IF (intoffer IS NULL) THEN
    SET intoffer = 1;
  ELSE
    SET intoffer = intoffer + 1;
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO test1 (asda) VALUES (intoffer);
end;
```

This is another procedure throwing same error. After removing the if..end-if both the code seems to work fine.

Comment: You are selecting `*` in your cursor. Are you completely sure that table test11 has exactly 4 fields and they are of the same type as your target list?

Comment: Also, I would wrap the if (for the insert) with another if that would execute only if done = false.

Comment: @FDavidov Yes there are only 4 fields in test11. I've tried everything it is not working. i tried creating a simple procedure with if..end-if statements and that one is also throwing syntax error.

Comment: Edit your question and include the declaration of both test1 and test11 tables, along with the contents of test11.

Comment: @FDavidov added the declaration of both the table

Comment: My friend... check your example. The source table has 4 VARCHAR fields while you are fetching them into two VARCHARs, a DATE and an INT. I suggest you change the types of your variables i1..i4 to varchar(20) and retry. If still not working, post the result after the update.

Comment: @FDavidov the code is working fine without the if statement. Anyways i even tried with 4 varchars (i1..i4) throws the same error at line 14- the end if line.

Comment: The IF is `if i4=22 then`. Try `if i4='22' then` (while i4 is also VARCHAR).

Comment: Avoid this type of comments (difficult to read). Add it as an EDIT to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are Missing `fetch from`

```
drop procedure if exists test;

delimiter $$
create procedure `test`() 
begin 
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE i1 VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE i2 DATE;
    DECLARE i3 VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE i4 INT; 
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test11;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN curs1;
    insertLoop: LOOP 
    FETCH FROM curs1 INTO i1,i2,i3,i4;
    if i4=22 then
        insert into test1(abc) values(i1);
    end if ;
    END LOOP insertLoop;
    CLOSE curs1; 
end ;

;;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Still the error persists. I don't know what i'm doing wrong but it is probably something stupid. unable to figure it out.

Comment: The `FROM` is optional.

Comment: it is running well on my mysql system.